# How to Configure RubyMine to Prevent Commits with YARD Return Type Errors?

Tags: ruby, rubymine, pre-commit-hook, yard

I'm working on a Ruby project using RubyMine as my IDE, and I'm utilizing YARD. I'm curious if there's a way to configure RubyMine to restrict commits that contain YARD return type mismatch errors.

Consider the following example:

```rb
# @param [Integer] integer input 
# @return [String] 
def foo(input)
  input # This causes a type mismatch
end
```

In the code above, there's a clear mismatch between the specified return type in the YARD comment and the actual return type of the method.

While I'm aware of RubyMine's ability to display YARD errors in the editor window (as shown in the screenshot below), I haven't found a built-in feature that actively prevents commits if such a type mismatch is detected.

[image: RubyMine configure]

Is there a way to configure RubyMine, perhaps through plugins or external tools, to enforce this check before allowing a commit? If not directly in RubyMine, is there an alternative approach I could use to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What version control system are you using? And are you using a supplementary tool such as Github?

Comment: @Schwern Yes I am using Github.

Comment: Is this just so you can make sure the documentation is non-contradictory? Obviously your minimalist example conveys a point but also neither input nor output can be of a guaranteed type for that method. Additionally I am not certain how RubyMine/YARD is able to infer this at all times given that ruby is a duck-typed language, other than relying on the notation provided (which is clearly fallible)

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes I want to make sure for the YARD to describe the method correctly. I don't know how it is possible but as I turn the option in my screenshot above to make error in all scopes, I can find all the mismatches in my IDE tab. There is also the parameter type mismatch check option.

Comment: @engineersmnky It can't infer at all times, but it can find contradictions, and the IDE can generate type signatures.

Comment: If you want to go all in on type annotations, there's [rbs](https://github.com/ruby/rbs) and [sorbet](https://sorbet.org/) each with their own issues. They all have their issues. I've found YARD to be a nice compromise between the effort of type annotation and its rewards.

Comment: @Schwern I find YARD to be excellent for documentation but I wouldn't ever consider it for type checking. That being said I am not a fan of type checking in Ruby at all. Objects are simply a collection of methods and state, walks like a duck, talks like a duck is freeing.

Answer (score 2):

> ...is there an alternative approach I could use to achieve this functionality?

I'm against both IDE-specific checks, and mandatory pre-commit checks. Here's why...

If you do this in your IDE, then they only work in your particular IDE and only for you. It's better to do this for the whole project.

Pre-commit checks are usually handled by your version control system, but they can get extremely tedious and slow if they're required for every single commit. Furthermore, requiring every commit to pass every test and every code quality check is extremely restrictive; during large or complex refactorings it's often useful to commit even when things are broken.

Is it necessary that every commit be perfect? If you're using a distributed version control system such as Git, commits are local; they only affect you until you push them. A broken commit is not nearly as important as a broken push. Even then, [you should always be working in a branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow), so a broken branch is also not important. The important moment is when you are merging your branch into the main code; that is when strenuous testing must be done to avoid breaking the code for everyone else.

---

It's better to do mandatory code quality checks during the branch merge review process (for example, [a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks)) and they should be automated. That way everyone's code gets checked.

Simplest thing to do is to add whatever checks you like to your Rakefile, then anyone has the option to make use of them. A single `rake check` can run all code quality checks. If you like, you can add a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to run your checks before committing, but don't force that on the whole project. Only your branch review process should require these checks.

Systems like Github have their own ways to integrate these checks into your review process which you may want to use.